# Tensorflow.js is there a list of all the identifiers

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, identifier, tensorflow.js

I'm a bit new to Tensorflow, I started to user Tensorflow.js for a project but I'm running across a few issues : in many field (s.a. activation, optimizer, loss, metrics, etc.) we can use a string to reference an object that fit our need, for some we can use a direct object reference (s.a. tf.losses.sigmoidCrossEntropy) and I found this version way easier because I can't find the identifier I need, this must be stored somewhere but where is it ? Is there a list of all the possible identifier ? (I searched stack, google and quant but I can't find anything...)

In advance, thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not exactly "documentation", and it's obviously not very easy to find, but at least it will solve your concrete problem now: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/f111dc03a87ab7664688011812beba4691bae455/tfjs-layers/src/keras_format/loss_config.ts#L16

Similarly, for other string identifiers (activations, metrics, constraints, initializers, and regularizers), see the neighboring files under https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-layers/src/keras_format.

In general these should match the string identifiers used for Python Keras.  For instance, https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy shows `name='categorical_crossentropy'`.  However, the TFJS implementations may not be up to date with the Python Keras ones (in particular, any new losses etc. added in the last year or two on the Python side are probably not implemented in TFJS yet).

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow.js Layers follows the Keras API, so you can find all the string identifiers in the docs at https://keras.io.  For instance, https://keras.io/activations/ lists 'softmax', 'elu', etc.

sebastian-speitel's answer is also correct that there is generally a 1:1 correspondence between the class/function names shown in the [TF.js API docs](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/) and the string representations.

One wrinkle: Keras uses snake_case string identifiers such as `hard_sigmoid`, but in TF.js we require lowerCamelCase, e.g. `hardSigmoid`.  (Most identifiers are a single word, in which case there's no difference).

We should certainly document this better in the TF.js API docs.  Tracking at https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/1315.

Answer (score -1):

Under [losses](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.15.3/#Training-Losses) in the official document you can find all possible loss-functions. The same for the other ones.

I'm not 100% certain, but every one of them should be able to be used as string reference.

Comment: Downvote. While the loss functions are indeed documented there, the string names are _not_ the same as the function names represented. Examples: softmaxCrossentropy (this is actually `categoricalCrossentropy`); sigmoidCrossentropy (I have no idea what this actually is).